# Trying to randomly generate numbers that divide evenly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to solve this problem but no luck, I have a function that is responsible for the logic but to be honest I don't think that that is the problem, I think that the issue is in the way that the variables are being read. If anyone can help it would be a great deal. What is happening when I run the code is it seems like just random numbers are generated without any logic. What I am expecting is for the randomly generated numbers to be equally divided to not have a remainder.

Function:

```
struct MathContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = VariableViewModel()
    
    @State var parent: MathView
    
    // realistic numbers ... only for subtraction and division
    
    // realistic numbers ... only for subtraction and division
    
    func numbersGenerator() {
        viewModel.numTemp1 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber1)
        viewModel.numTemp2 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber2)
        
        if viewModel.numTemp1 > viewModel.numTemp2 && operatorName == "Subtraction" {
            viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1
            viewModel.num2 = viewModel.numTemp2
        }
        if viewModel.numTemp2 > viewModel.numTemp1 && operatorName == "Subtraction" {
            viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp2
            viewModel.num2 = viewModel.numTemp1
        }
        if viewModel.numTemp1 == viewModel.numTemp2 && operatorName == "Subtraction" {
            viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1
            viewModel.num2 = viewModel.numTemp2
        }
        if operatorName == "Division" {
            
            // applied zeros (/)
            if viewModel.zeroToggle == false {
            if viewModel.numTemp2 != 0 {
                if viewModel.numTemp1 % viewModel.numTemp2 == 0 {
                    viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1
                    viewModel.num2 = viewModel.numTemp2
                }
                else {
                    numbersGenerator()
                }
            }
            else {
                numbersGenerator()
            }
                viewModel.result = viewModel.num1 / viewModel.num2
            }
        // no zeros (/)
            if viewModel.zeroToggle == true {
            if viewModel.numTemp1 != 0 && viewModel.numTemp2 != 0 {
                if viewModel.numTemp1 % viewModel.numTemp2 == 0 {
                    viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1
                    viewModel.num2 = viewModel.numTemp2
                }
                else {
                    numbersGenerator()
                }
            }
            else {
                numbersGenerator()
            }
        }
        
        if operatorName == "Multiplicaton" {
            viewModel.num1 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber1)
            viewModel.num2 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber2)
        }
        }
    }
    
    func passButton() {
        numbersGenerator()
        viewModel.num1 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber1)
        viewModel.num2 = Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber1)
    }
```

ViewModel is a file where the variables are coming from, here is the code for that:

```
    // temp value
    var numTemp1 = 0
    var numTemp2 = 0

    // Randomizing numbers for easy Multiplication
@Published var num1 = Int.random(in: 0...5)
@Published var num2 = Int.random(in: 0...5)
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code to reproduce anything and you haven't described what result you're expecting vs. what you're encountering instead. Can you add some detail?

Comment: @jnpdx My bad, I will fix it.

Comment: Please say clearly what output you wish to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution could be to check if the generated number is divisible by 2 using the Modulo operator `%`

if it is not add 1

```
@Published var generatedNum  = Int.random(in: 0...5)
@Published var num1 = generatedNum % 2 == 0 ? generatedNum : generatedNum++
```

I dont use Swift so do not know if that is the correct syntax. But have seen that both Modulo and Ternary Operators exist

Comment: `BinaryInteger` protocol has a method called `isMultiple(of:)` exactly for this purpose. `generatedNum.isMultiple(of: 2)`

Comment: @LeoDabus So something like this:  `viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1.isMultiple(of: 2) `

Comment: @LeoDabus The problem with that for me is it is giving me an error saying that  "Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'Int'" In my case, viewModel.numTemp1 is the generatedNum

Comment: `generatedNum.isMultiple(of: 2)` is meant to be a drop-in replacement for `generatedNum % 2 == 0`

Comment: `viewModel.num1 = viewModel.numTemp1.isMultiple(of: 2) ? viewModel.numTemp1 : viewModel.numTemp1++`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to generate a random multiple of some number (**X**). If that's the case, it would be easier to just multiply the random number by **X**. Assuming **X** is 5 . . .

```swift
viewModel.numTemp1 = 5 * Int.random(in: 0...difficultyNumber1)
```

If you want to enforce a maximum on the generated multiple, you can just use integer division to find the max to use for the random generator.

```swift
randMax = Int(difficultyNumber1 / 5)
viewModel.numTemp1 = 5 * Int.random(in: 0...randMax)
```

Comment: Ali's answer was the first thing that came to my mind.  If I want to generate a random number between 0 and 100 that is divisible by 2 then I generate a number between 0 and 50 and then multiply by two.